# How to express a Hash + Range in JSON for dynamodb getItem on Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a table called Message in dynamodb. The key is composed of a Hash (called entryStamp as a Number), and a Range ( userId as a String).

I'm trying to do a getItem on it using Node.js Lambda.  I know how to getItem for a different table with a Hash only key, and it works.

But I can't find documentation on how to modify my json to express the Range part of the key.

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var messageIdParts = event.messageId.split("-");
    var desiredStampString = messageIdParts[0];
    var desiredSendStamp = Number(desiredStampString);
    var userId = messageIdParts[1];

    var params = {
        "ConsistentRead": false,
        "Key": {
            HashKeyElement: { "entryStamp": desiredSendStamp },
            RangeKeyElement: { "userId": userId }
           },
        "ProjectionExpression": "message",
        "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "NONE",
        "TableName": "Message"
    }
    try {
        dynamo.getItem(params, context.done);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Exception for getItem: " + e);
    }
};
```

Here's the info on the table from the DynamoDB "Details" tab:

```
Table Name: Message
Primary Hash Key:   entryStamp (Number)
Primary Range Key:  userId (String)
Table Status:   Active
```

Here's what I pass to event.messageId:

```
{
    "messageId": "1443768744451-testUser"
}
```

Thanks in advance!
When I send the above to getItem, I get this:

```
{
   "errorMessage": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
   "errorType": "ValidationException",
   "stackTrace": [
        "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:40:27)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:100:18)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:604:14)",
        "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:21:12)",
        "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:9)",
"Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:606:12)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/dynamodb-doc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:104:18)"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What are `desiredSendStamp` and `userId` actual values in this example? Could you also share the table attribute definition for the `Message` table?

Comment: looks okay. are you sure that the hash key is N and that userId is a String (S)?

Answer (score 2):

I think the Key definition in `params` is not quite right, you do not need to specify `HashKeyElement` and `RangeKeyElement`.  Try:

```
var params = {
        "ConsistentRead": false,
        "Key": {
            "entryStamp": desiredSendStamp,
            "userId": userId
           },
        "ProjectionExpression": "message",
        "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "NONE",
        "TableName": "Message"
};
```

Also, you can use the [DocumentClient class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) in the aws-sdk package now, if you upgrade.